# VBA Loop Through Pivot Table Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that loops through a list on one worksheet and then is to pick an item from a corresponding pivot table, which does not work. The pivot tables are created by a macro that I made, the pivot tables are produced just fine. For the life of me though I cannot figure out why when I set the CurrentPage portion of the pivot table equal to my variable it does not set it. Here is the code that I am using to loop:

```
Sub m4_HCAHPS_Macro()

Dim vPhys2 As String
Dim vrow2 As Long
Dim vlastphys2 As String

vrow2 = 1

nextRow2:

Sheets("hcahps doctors").Activate
Range("A" & CStr(vrow2)).Select

vPhys2 = ActiveCell.Value

If Len(vPhys2) < 1 Then
    MsgBox "All Done Here"
    GoTo subcomplete
End If

Sheets("hcahps").Activate
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HcahpsPivotcurrentTable").PivotFields("Doctor").CurrentPage = vPhys2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HcahpsPivotTrendTable").PivotFields("Doctor").CurrentPage = vPhys2
End With

Sheets("hcahps report").Activate

vrow2 = vrow2 + 1
vlastphys2 = vPhys2

GoTo nextRow2

subcomplete:

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try to remove `with` statement and use just `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HcahpsPivotcurrentTable").PivotFields("Doctor").CurrentPage = vPhys2`

Comment: That worked like a charm, but why?

Comment: your `with` statement was slightly worng. E.g. you could use `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HcahpsPivotcurrentTable").PivotFields("Doctor")` and then *in next* line `.CurrentPage = vPhys2` and, of course, `End With`

Comment: also 1) using `GoTo` is not good style of programming. 2) [**How to avoid using Select/Active statements**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: ok, did not know that I needed to do `_` then `.CurrentPage = vPhys2` Thank you for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I am brand new to VBA so I appreciate the helpful advice.

Comment: if you would like to put all of that in an answer, then I can accept it

Comment: There is no need:) someone else already posted an answer for you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tips for rewriting this code to be a bit easier to follow and doesn't use common pitfalls of `Active` and `goto` statements.

```
Sub m4_HCAHPS_Macro()

    Dim vPhys2 As String
    Dim vrow2 As Long: vrow2 = 1
    Dim vlastphys2 As String

    Dim wksDoctors As Worksheet
    Dim wkshcahps As Worksheet

    Set wkshcahps = Sheets("hcahps")
    Set wksDoctors = Sheets("hcahps doctors")

    vPhys2 = wksDoctors.Range("A" & CStr(vrow2)).Value

    Do While (Len(vPhys2) < 1)
        wkshcahps.PivotTables("HcahpsPivotcurrentTable").PivotFields("Doctor").CurrentPage = vPhys2
        wkshcahps.PivotTables("HcahpsPivotTrendTable").PivotFields("Doctor").CurrentPage = vPhys2

        vrow2 = vrow2 + 1
        vlastphys2 = vPhys2

        vPhys2 = wksDoctors.Range("A" & CStr(vrow2)).Value
    Loop

    MsgBox "All Done Here"
End Sub
```

As @simoco said, your with statment wasn't set properly.  You can't set a value in the with statement it self.  You can set it within the with block like this if you wanted to:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HcahpsPivotTrendTable").PivotFields("Doctor")
    .CurrentPage = vPhys2
End With
```